# Mutual information for a continuous uniform distribution

Tags: integration, matlab, information-theory, uniform-distribution, entropy

I'm trying to compute using matlab the mutual information for an $ \infty $-PAM input (the limit of a very dense PAM constellation) for a range of snr and I got stuck.

I'm working with a real-valued scalar Gaussian channel with input power constrained to unity and standard Gaussian noise $ N \sim (0, 1) $. The output of the channel is given by, 
$$ y = \sqrt{ \gamma } x + n $$

I know that under the power input constraint the input is uniformly distributed on $ \left[ -\sqrt{ 3 }, \sqrt{ 3 } \right] $.

I found that in HIGH-SNR regime, there exists a gap between the Shannon capacity and the capacity achieved with $ \infty $-PAM around 0.254 bits. I know this is called the shaping loss and represents the loss of using an uniform input rather than a Gaussian input.

I know how to compute that. But, I got stuck trying to compute the capacity for a range of snr or $ \gamma $. I tried using the formula,
$$ I(x;y) = h(y) - h(n) $$
with $ f_{y}(y) = \int f_{x}(x)f_{y|x}(y|x) dx $ and I got
$$ f_{y} (y) = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 \sqrt{ 3 \gamma } } \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } \int_{ \frac{ y - \sqrt{3} }{ \sqrt{2} } }^{ \frac{ y + \sqrt{3} }{ \sqrt{2} } } \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt{ \pi } } e^{ -t^{2} } dt \\
= \frac{ 1 }{ 2 \sqrt{ 3 \gamma } } \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } \left[ \text{erf} \left( \frac{ y + \sqrt{ 3 \gamma } }{ \sqrt{ 2 } } \right) - \text{erf} \left( \frac{ y - \sqrt{ 3 \gamma } }{ \sqrt{ 2 } } \right) \right] $$

I tried to compute $ h(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{y} (y) \log_{2} f_{y} (y) $ and the integral does not converge. I tried with int$(\cdot)$ and integral$(\cdot)$ methods in matlab.

I also tried approximating the $ \text{erf}(\cdot) $ function with Taylor series expansion
$$ erf(x) = \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt{ \pi } } \sum_{ n = 0 }^{ \infty } \frac{ (-1)^{n} x^{ 2n + 1 } }{ n!(2n + 1) } $$
but it didn't work.

I think there would be another approach to solve this problem, but I don't know it. So,

Could you help me? How can I obtain a more manageable integral? Is my approach correct?

I appreciate any help!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the integrand has the general form of
$$g(z,a)\log_2 g(z,a)$$
where $g(z,a)=\mathrm{erf}(z+a) - \mathrm{erf}(z-a)$. 
Try to prove that the integrand $\sim0$ after, say $z>a+\delta$, $2\leq\delta\leq 3$ ($\delta =3$ could be good enough).
After this you should be integrate it as a proper integral, i..e $\int_{-{a+\delta}}^{a+\delta}...$ without stability problem.

Note, that there is `erf` function in matlab, so you don't need to use it's Taylor expansion.

If you want to try another integration function in matlab you can try 
`trapz`?

Comment: Thanks!! It works as you say, once plotted $ f_{y}(y) $ I saw that the most of probability is within a band arround $ \sqrt{3\gamma} $. Moreover, $ \lim_{ y \to \infty } g(y,a) \log( g(y,a) ) = 0 $. Then, the integral works $ \int_{ - a - \delta }^{ a + \delta } \cdots $. Thanks for your help.